# Need formula to concatenate 2 cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nyzX.png)

Kindly help me solve this, my sheet as below

```
A         B
49146   011-9575-305M  
        011-9688  
49158   022-8745E 
49180   306-251-003  
        306-E700-CAP-KIT 
        306-E700-SP 
        306-E700-SP-DCL-PIPE  
        306-E700-SP-DCL-PNT
```

I need out put as below,

```
A         B
49146   011-9575-305M, 011-9688 (B1 & B2 together when A2 = "")
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What Excel are you using?

Comment: According to the [Excel tag information](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/excel/info), this post belongs at [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a helper column.  In C2 put:

```
=IF(OR(AND(A2="",A3<>""),B3="",AND(A2<>"",A3<>"")),B2,B2 & ", " & C3)
```

And copy down.

Then use the following VLOOKUP() to get your answer:

```
=VLOOKUP(A14,$A$2:$C$9,3,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Mr. Scott, No words to say thanks for your help.  how amazing... great.. Thanks a ton. the only question is how the data comes in A14, but no worries I copied down the cells and got the desired output by Vlookup. RESPECT...

Comment: @Manzoor VLOOKUP grabs the first row where the criteria is met.  Please mark as correct by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer it is something only you can do.

Comment: Done Sir, answer marked. Just correct me If I am doing wrong. I have used your formula in column C and get the output then I used "go to blanks->=A2 cntl+enter to fill all the values. then remove duplicates. Thanking you in advance once again.